# Vue update component during synchronous function call

Tags: vue.js

I have a button triggering a long runing function (heavy synchronous calculation made locally):

```
<button :disabled="running" @click="run">Run</button>

data () {
 return {
   running: false;
 }
}

methods: {
  run() {
    this.running=true;
    veryLongRunningCall();
    this.running=false;
  }
}
```

But vue updates the button only after the run() function is terminated. How can tell vue to force update the button after I set running to true?
I tried to make the run function async and call this.$nextTick() but it doesn't work.

Comment: please mentions what is inside that function `veryLongRunningCall`

Comment: Nothing interesting inside veryLongRunningCall, could be sleep(5000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
methods: {
  run() {
    this.running=true;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      veryLongRunningCall();
      this.running=false;
    },0);
  }
}
```

So I give back the control to the main event loop so it can refresh the page and after execute my task containing veryLongRunningCall() call.

It works but it would be better (and perfect!) if there were another and dedicated way than setTimeout to add a task to the main event loop.

Thank you BroiSatse, you put me on the way!

Comment: Yes, this did the trick for me as well! Can't shake the feeling that this approach is a bit 'hacky', but for now this will do..

Comment: Can confirm that it works, one day headache is gone

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single-threaded language and it is sing an event loop to handle its synchronisation. This is why there is no `sleep` in JS and instead we have `setTimeout` which deals with time events.

So, to solve your issue, you need to find a way of making your longRunningCall as asynchronous (and event based) as possible, as any synchronous call will completely halt all javascript on the page.

You can have a read here: https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_async-js.html

### **Previous answer**

Vue runs in cycles called ticks and will only update the views once the tick completed. You can however force it to execute the task after the current tick:

```
methods: {
  run() {
    this.running=true;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      veryLongRunningCall();
      this.running=false;
    }
  }
}
```

`Vue.nextTick` (available on prototype as `this.$nextTick`) will register a callback to execute after the current tick completes, so it will execute `veryLongRuningCall` after the view is updated to reflect `this.running=true`

However, this will cause next tick to take much more tiem than required - which could cause other elements not to update their view until this particluar task completes. It is much better solution to make your `veryLongRunningCall` asyncronous (unless you have  a very good reason for not doing this). You could easily use Promise for this:

```
methods: {
  run() {
    this.running=true;
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(veryLongRunningCall)
      .then(() => this.running = false)
  }
}
```

Comment: None of the solutions works. I already tried to manage with $nextTick but it looks like I am missing something

Comment: Interesting, I think it is not really Vue issue but rather a result of javascript architecture. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you are blocking the main thread. You could wrap your very long task in a promise, it will be passed to the web API, then to the callback que, and the event loop grabs your callback from the que and puts it on the callstack, and after its reaches the callstack the main thread is blocked again till this task is completed. So, i would say you maybe go with a worker thread.

You also need to know you have limited access in the webworker, like you cant access the dom